# Return a view of an Activity that is not the Codename One main Activity

Tags: codenameone

Inside a native interface, can I return as PeerComponent a View declared in an Activity that is not the main Activity used by Codename One? In other words, can I use a custom Activity?

My issue is that I have to use an Activity that implements an interface provided by the SDK that I’m trying to use.

Could you show me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that might be possible with some Android backflips I have a better idea that would also solve a lot of other similar use cases. Albeit this is a bit of a sledgehammer solution so it might be problematic in some cases.

For next weeks release we'll add the build hint: `android.customActivity` where you can define the full class name of your custom activity subclass. Your activity must derive from `com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity` and the stub class will derive from that activity. This way you can implement and override any method you desire within the activity class.

The case where this would be a problem would be when two cn1libs choose to use this approach. Obviously only one can "win" so this isn't ideal. But this is a rare enough case that it shouldn't matter.